# SELECT vin sorted by different ODO mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have an DB like

| vin | ODO |
| --- | --- |
| 666 | 12 |
| 666 | 12 |
| 666 | 13 |
| 555 | 333 |
| 555 | 333 |
| 666 | 111 |
| 666 | 111 |
| 333 | 122 |
| 111 | 11 |
| 111 | 11 |
| 111 | 12 |

$sql =   "SELECT vin FROM cars GROUP BY vin HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY vin"; return me a vins thats is more then one time but i need to get a vin with different ODO value like
111 and 666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT vin 
FROM cars 
GROUP BY vin 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT odo) > 1 
ORDER BY vin
```